# sitemesh expends more time with larger page size

Tags: sitemesh

Using sitemesh Version 2.4.2

It expends 10ms when page-size 50k;
It expends 30ms when page-size 100k;
It expends 60ms when page-size 300k.

How can I reduce Time-consuming when `page-size` becomes larger?

Comment: Where are you getting your times from?

Comment: From after [struts-execute]; [sitemesh filter] spends the times.

Comment: Can you show any of your pages? The answer will be dependent on what the pages do, unless your pages are all completely static.